# Diferencia entre fetch y fetchall en PHP?

Tags: php

Quisiera saber cual es la diferencia entre fetch y fetchall en php, por lo que vi por ahi fetch te devuelve un solo campo y fetchall todos los campos, pero utilizando PDO me parece que no importa cual utilize, total uso (PDO:: FETCH_ASSOC), pero igual quisiera saber la diferencia, gracias :)

Comment: fetch() va a trabajar para devolver una fila de registros mientras que fetchAll() trabaja sobre todo el conjunto de registros; ahora si lo usas como fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) te transforma el conjunto de datos en un array de tipo asociativo

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Son dos cosas distintas mezcladas en la pregunta:

### [`fetch`](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php)

abre como un puntero listo para **recorrer los datos uno por uno** (generalmente mediante un ciclo `while`). Es el método recomendado cuando se esperan muchos datos, porque de ese modo no tendrás problemas de memoria.

Ejemplo de código:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
while ($fila = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  $datos []= $fila;
}
```

Aquí `$datos` será un array asociativo que se irá llenando con una fila cada vez que el puntero avanza dentro del `while`.

También, se puede imprimir el dato *in situ*  si no se necesita para transportarlo a otro lugar:

```
while ($fila = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  echo $fila["nombre"]." ".$fila["apellido"].PHP_EOL;
}
```

---

### [`fetchAll`](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

**te trae todos los datos de golpe**, sin abrir ningún puntero, almacenándolos en un array. Se recomienda cuando no se esperan demasiados resultados que podrían provocar problemas de memoria al querer guardar de golpe en un array miles o millones de filas ¡!  provenientes de un `SELECT`.

Ejemplo de código:

```
$resultado = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($resultado);
```

En este caso `$resultado` es un array asociativo con todos los datos de la consulta. Si se quieren leer las filas que hay en él, se puede implementar un bucle que recorra el array:

```
foreach ($resultado as $row){
    echo $row["nombre"]." ".$row["apellido"].PHP_EOL;
}
```

Es casi lo mismo que en `fetch`, sólo que aquí no estamos actuando sobre un recorrido de los datos a través de un puntero, sino sobre los datos ya almacenados en una variable. Si por ejemplo antes de esto nosotros cerramos el statemente, ya tenemos los datos en `$resultado` y podremos leerlos. En `fetch` si cerramos el statement no podremos leer los datos.

---

En cuanto a **`PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`** es sólo una forma de representación de los datos. Uno de los [`fetch_style`](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php) que existen, el cual indica que quieres los resultados en forma de array asociativo donde la clave es el nombre de cada columna y el valor el dato perteneciente a esa columna. Lo puedes usar tanto con `fetch` como con `fetchAll`.

Cabe destacar que tanto para `fetch` como para `fetchAll` el estilo por defecto es `PDO::FETCH_BOTH`. Pero se puede establecer un estilo por defecto sea al objeto conexión mediante el método [`setAttribute`](http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.setattribute.php), cambiando el valor de la constante `PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE`; sea a un statement específico mediante el método [`setFechMode`](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.setfetchmode.php).

Comment: Tendrías algún link de referencia sobre las velocidades y el uso de memoria entre `fetch()` y `fetchAll()`? De lo que he estado investigando en diferentes foros cada cual viene con su propio test y resultados diferentes en todos ellos. Por lo que he podido ver a menos que sean `unbuffered query:false` fetchAll es mas recomendable o al menos no hay diferencia de velocidad y la memoria en ambos casos es guardada por el PDO

Comment: @CristianS9 no tengo nada sobre eso. Puedes ver algunas preguntas de SO en inglés:  [Enlace1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770630/5587982) -  [Enlace2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13222923/5587982)  -  [Enlace3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3328794/5587982)