# Mostrar los datos de una tabla con una condición e ingresarlos a un ciclo foreach

Tags: php, mysql

Buen día chicos y chicas, infinitas gracias a todos los que ayudan a nosotros los novatos, tengo una consulta
Resulta que quiero imprimir una leyenda en un ticket para imprimir, el dato está en una tabla ya capturado en una columna "descripción" y llevan una columna "codigo", quiero traer todo los que coincidad con el "codigo" de la nota, por lo que utilizo una condición WHERE, les pongo el código

```
 $valorAbono = $valorVenta;
$itemAbono = "codigo";

$respuestaRegistro = ControladorAbonos::ctrMostrarAbono2($itemAbono, $valorAbono);
```

Al recibir la respuestaRegistro, la quiero ingresar a un ciclo foreach, ojo si no la ingreso al ciclo y la imprimo solo $repuestaRegistro["descripcion"] si me trae un dato ( la mayoría son 2 o 3 datos los que coinciden en ese mismo código), por eso lo quiero ingresar al ciclo, para traer todos los datos que coincidan con ese dato

```
foreach ($respuestaRegistro as $key => $value) {
          
    
$bloque4 = <<<EOF
<table>
<tr>
<td style="border: 2px solid #666; font-size:10px; width:60px; text-align:center"><center>$value[descripcion]</center> </td>
<
<td></td>
</tr>

</table>
EOF;



$pdf->writeHTML($bloque4, false, false, false, false, '');
}
```

y esto es lo que me trae

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo de mi modelo y mi controlador, están en diferentes páginas y las dos están requeridas al inicio del código

```
static public function ctrMostrarAbono2($item, $valor){

        $tabla = "registro_abonos";

        $respuesta = ModeloAbonos::mdlMostrarAbonos2($tabla, $item, $valor);

        return $respuesta;

    }

static public function mdlMostrarAbonos2($tabla, $item, $valor){

        if($item != null){

        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE $item = :$item ORDER BY codigo ASC");

        $stmt -> bindParam(":".$item, $valor, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $stmt -> execute();

        return $stmt -> fetch();

        }else{

            $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla");

            $stmt -> execute();

            return $stmt -> fetchAll();

        }

        $stmt -> close();

        $stmt = null;

    }
```

si mando las variables de $valorAbono e $itemAbono en null, resulta que si me trae toda la tabla, pero la necesito filtrada por los códigos :C

[image: si trae en null]

Ya lo he intentado todo y según yo, debería estar bien, ya que así lo he hecho en otras hojas, pero simplemente no me funciona, espero alguien pueda hecharme una mano, de antemano, muchas gracias

Comment: En la primera parte del `if` debes poner `fetchAll` para que te devuelva un array: **`return $stmt -> fetchAll();`** Al poner `fetch` sin más te traerá sólo la primera fila, y luego pasa lo que pasa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la primera parte del `if` debes poner `fetchAll` para que te devuelva un array: **`return $stmt -> fetchAll();`** Al poner `fetch` sin más te traerá sólo la primera fila, y luego pasa lo que pasa...

Por otra parte, tu función está mal, debes saber que cuando escribes un método o función **debes hacer todo lo que tengas que hacer antes del `return`**. Por tanto, estas dos líneas **no se ejecutarán nunca** en tu función actual, porque antes hay un `return`:

```
    $stmt -> close();
    $stmt = null;
```

Y además, son redundantes, hacen lo mismo.

Así está mejor la función:

```
static public function mdlMostrarAbonos2($tabla, $item, $valor){
    if($item != null){
        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE $item = :$item ORDER BY codigo ASC");
        $stmt -> bindParam(":$item", $valor, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt -> execute();
        $mData = $stmt -> fetchAll();
    }else{
        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla");
        $stmt -> execute();
        $mData = $stmt -> fetchAll();
    }
        $stmt = null;
        return $mData;
    }
```

Para más detalles sobre la diferencia entre `fetch()` t `fetchAll()` consulta esta pregunta: [Diferencia entre fetch y fetchall en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/184341/29967)

Comment: Infinitas gracias, efectivamente era eso, me adentro a leer la documentación que me mandaste para entenderla mejor, infinitas gracias por apoyarme