# Array de archivos en mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

- Estoy agregando productos a una página y por cada uno quiero tener un slider con fotos del mismo, pero no sé cómo agregar más de un archivo o si se puede con blob.
- Si tienen alguna solución aplicando matrices a una columna de la tabla o un array de archivos por así decirlo, me serviría para practicar.

```php
<div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="carousel-item active">
   <?php echo '<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['imagenes']) .' "/>'; ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

- Estos productos se generan con un `<?php foreach ($resultado as $row) { ?>`

Con éste código traigo los datos

```php
$db = new database();
$con = $db->conectar();
//
$sql = $con->prepare("SELECT id, nombre, precio, imagenes FROM productos WHERE activo=1");
$sql->execute();
//
$resultado = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
//
```

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende. Pulsa en [edit] y aclara tu problema. Por otra parte, no debes aplicar `fetch` y `fetchAll()` sobre un mismo conjunto de resultados. O aplicas `fetch` dentro de un bucle o aplicas `fetchAll` y luego lees los resultados dentro de un bucle. Creo que [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/184343/29967) podrá ayudarte a entender la diferencia entre ambos métodos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que quieres almacenar varias imágenes para cada producto, y por algún motivo quieres usar blob (es más recomendable tener las imágenes directamente en disco como archivos y servirlas), tendrías que crear una tabla nueva para guardarlas.

De forma que tendrías una tabla `productos` (con ID, nombre, precio y cualquier cosa que quieras) y una tabla `imagenes_productos` con un ID de imagen, el ID del producto al que pertenece y el contenido como blob.

Para sacar cada producto con sus imágenes, tendrías que obtener primero los productos, y luego para cada producto sus imágenes. La solución "sencilla" sería un bucle foreach por cada producto que recibes y para cada producto hacer un `SELECT * FROM imagenes_producto WHERE producto_id = ?` con el código de producto. Pero lo ideal sería seleccionar las imágenes de todos los productos (o al menos los que quieres recuperar) y luego agruparlas por producto en PHP (con un array asociativo `producto_id  => [imágenes]` o con una clase `Producto` que almacene todo).