# ¿Cómo mostrar muchas filas de forma eficiente con PHP y MySql?

Tags: php, mysql

Estimados estaría muy agradecido de su ayuda.

Tengo una consulta la cual devuelve una serie de filas según una determinada matrícula.

Para realizar una consulta a mi base de datos MySql utilizo la siguiente función.

```
<?php include 'bd.php';
class Conexion {
    //DECLARACION VARIABLES DE CONEXION Y BASE DE DATOS
    public $conexion;
    //CONECTAR A LA BASE DE DATOS
    public function __construct(){
        try {
        // Conectar
            $this->conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_SERVIDOR.";dbname=".DB_BASE, DB_USUARIO, DB_CLAVE);
        // Establecer el nivel de errores a EXCEPTION
            $this->conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $this->conexion->query('SET NAMES utf8');
            $this->conexion->query("SET lc_time_names = 'es_ES'");
            
        } catch (PDOException $e){
            echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
        }

    }  
    //CERRAR LA CONEXION 
    public function desconectar(){
        $this->conexion = null ;
    }
    //OBTENER CONJUNTO DE DATOS
    public function obtenerdatos($datos,$tabla,$condiciones,$conjunto) {
        $query = $this->conexion->prepare("SELECT $datos FROM $tabla WHERE $condiciones");
        $query->execute($conjunto);
        $datos = $query->fetchALL();
        return $datos;
    }       
}

?>
```

Luego utilizo esta función para obtener los datos

```
$con = new Conexion(); 
$datos = $con->obtenerdatos("*","item","matricula = ? AND tipo = ?",['CC-AFL','AD']);
```

Resulta que los datos se muestran sin problemas de forma local ya sean muchas filas o pocas filas, pero al ser subida la web a un servidor, al querer mostrar una matrícula con muchas filas me da un error 500, pero cuando la matrícula tiene menos filas no ocurre ese error, que puede suceder, estara mal configurado el servidor ?

Los datos los muestro paginados, pero para simplificar el codigo puse la consulta directa

Comment: Los errores de apache, incluidos los 500, muestran información ampliada en su log de errores.  Dicho archivo, en un hosting linux, suele estar en la carpeta /var/log/apache2 y suele llamarse error_log.  Si no tienes acceso a ella quizás debas consultar a los administradores del mismo para que te pasen esa información. También pudiera ser que la encontrases en tu propio archivo de errores, pues segun sea el hosting, dispones de acceso a el en tu propia cuenta. A malas, prueba agregando `ini_set('display_errors', '1'); ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1'); error_reporting(E_ALL); ` a tu script

Comment: Revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/184343/29967). El Manual de PHP es claro, y aconseja no usar `fetchAll()` cuando se esperan muchos registros, porque la memoria del servidor y/o la red podrían verse saturadas, cosa que ocurre muy probablemente en tu caso. Considera usar `fetch` incorporándolo a tu código de paginación.

Comment: `fetchAll` hace un dump de todos los registros a la memoria, no se debe usar cuando la cantidad de datos es muy grande, lo dice [la documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetchall.php#refsect1-pdostatement.fetchall-returnvalues). Usar [fetch](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php), el cual solo cargará en memoria el registro actual a medida que se recorre el objeto PDO obtenido.