# Recorrer un array devuelto con fetch() en PDO de PHP

Tags: php, pdo

Tengo el siguiente array obtenido de hacer una consulta en la base de datos:

```
array(3) 
{ 
   ["CodPed"]=> int(17) 
   ["Fecha"]=> string(10) "2023-02-24" 
   ["Enviado"]=> int(0) 
}
```

Este array esta almacenado en la variable $resultado y sale de la siguiente consulta:

```
function comprobarHistorial($usuario,$fecha){
    $base=conexionBD();
    $consulta="SELECT CodPed, Fecha, Enviado FROM pedidos INNER JOIN 
           hospitales 
           ON pedidos.Hospital=hospitales.CodHosp 
           WHERE pedidos.Fecha=:fecha AND pedidos.Hospital=:usuario";
    $resultado=$base->prepare($consulta);
    $resultado->bindParam(":fecha",$fecha);
    $resultado->bindParam(":usuario",$usuario);
    $resultado->execute();

    while ($fila = $resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        return $fila;
  
    }
}
```

Esta consulta devuelve los pedidos que ha hecho ese usuario en concreto en una fecha seleccionada :

[image: consulta]

Para recorrer el resultado y mostrarlo en una tabla utilizo el siguiente código:

```
   <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Codigo</th>
              <th>Fecha</th>
              <th>Enviado</th>
            </tr>  
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
            var_dump($resultado);
            foreach($resultado as $fila){ 
              echo "<tr>";
               foreach($resultado as $fila=>$dato){
                echo "<td>$dato</td>";  
               }
               echo "</tr>";
              }
           
            ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Pero el resultado es la misma fila repetida ahora:

[image: resultado]

Comment: ¿Por qué implementas el `foreach`?, ¿podría haber más filas anidadas? Esto te crea un `tr` por cada valor del array, y esos valores parecen estar destinados a ser celdas de la tabla, no filas. Sería interesante ver cómo creas `$resultado`, creo que es allí donde está tu problema, no estás creando bien los datos en ese punto, puede que hayas omitido un nivel de anidación.

Comment: @A. Cedano Voy a reeditar, he hecho modificaciones que casi dan lo que busco pero no del todo.

Comment: Bien.  Muestra el bloque de código donde creas `$resultado`.

Comment: creo que puede ser un foreach anidado lo que necesito verdad? voy a probar

Comment: vale no, y es que el array no me devuelve la segunda fila de la consulta tampoco, solo la primera

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es justo lo que sospechaba, al poner un `return` dentro del `while` no te devolverá **todas la filas**, el código retornará en cuanto encuentre el `return`, es decir, en la primera fila, volviendo a quien llamó al método. Y además, las filas no estarán dentro de un array global, a ese me refería cuando dije en mi comentario que falta un nivel de anidación.

De este modo debería funcionar:

```
function comprobarHistorial($usuario,$fecha){   
    $base=conexionBD();
    $consulta="SELECT CodPed, Fecha, Enviado FROM pedidos INNER JOIN 
               hospitales 
               ON pedidos.Hospital=hospitales.CodHosp 
               WHERE pedidos.Fecha=:fecha AND pedidos.Hospital=:usuario";
    $resultado=$base->prepare($consulta);
    $resultado->bindParam(":fecha",$fecha);
    $resultado->bindParam(":usuario",$usuario);
    $resultado->execute();
    $allData=array();    
    while ($fila = $resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      $allData[] = $fila; 
    }
    return $allData;
}
```

He creado un array llamado `$allData`, el cual voy llenando dentro del `while` y finalmente, **una vez terminado el `while`** retornamos ese array.

Para mostrar los datos, no tienes que cambiar nada, déjalo como lo tenías originalmente, es decir **un solo bucle: `foreach($resultado as $fila){`**.

Usaré `printf` por ser más cómodo, claro y elegante:

```
        <?php
        var_dump($resultado);
        foreach($resultado as $fila){ 
          printf ("<tr>
                      <td>%s</td>
                      <td>%s</td>
                      <td>%s</td>
                  </tr>",
                      $fila['CodPed'],
                      $fila['Fecha'],
                      $fila['Enviado']);
         }
       
        ?>
```

Comment: Correcto! que alivio. Gracias. Si no le  parece mal, doy la respuesta valida a otro usuario que ha respondido algo parecido que funciona también pero es nuevo, para darle reputación. Aunque usted ya me ha respondido varias vaya !

Comment: @JoseL. quien decide la respuesta aceptada es el autor de la pregunta, eres totalmente libre en ese sentido. No obstante, se suele marcar la respuesta que responde con mayor claridad al problema y se valora la calidad de las respuestas, etc independientemente de otros criterios como antigüedad, anteriores respuestas datas, etc. He añadido algo con respecto al `foreach` porque vi que en la edición cambiaste esa parte, tratando de corregir el error original. No hace falta un `foreach` anidado, sino construir bien el array que retornas desde el método.

Comment: SI, tienes razón. Quiero aprovechar a preguntar una cosa. Si es necesario abro pregunta nueva. Cuando realizo un pedido, se actualiza la BD correctamente, pero si doy a refrescar el navegador de la aplicacion, se repite el pedido solo y se va añadiendo a la BD.

Comment: @JoseL. darle a *refrescar* en muchos casos equivale a **volver a mandar** la información que haya. Por lo que dices, eso es lo que estaría pasando en tu código. Dicho eso, estamos hablando de otro problema distinto y deberías plantearlo en una nueva pregunta, explicando lo que pasa y mostrando el código implicado. Conviene saber que actualmente se usa Ajax o la nueva API Fetch de Javascript para mandar y traer cosas entre cliente y servidor, así, ya no es necesario refrescar la página cada vez que quieres mandar o traer algo nuevo entre cliente / servidor.

Comment: Vale, no es que necesite refrescar. Como es un ejercicio en localhost, solo refresco para ver si las modificaciones en el código se visualizan correctamente. Y cada vez que lo hago, se añade el registro de nuevo. Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: @JoseL. seguramente porque en tu código, nada más entrar a ese archivo se recogen los datos y se envían para ser insertados. Al hablar de *ejercicio*, quizá no puedes usar Ajax o la API Fetch, pero debes saber que para escenarios actuales ya no se refresca la página para verificar que algo en el servidor tuvo éxito o error. Precisamente, mediante Ajax o Fetch, puedes: 1. Mandar algo al servidor (por ejemplo haciendo click en un botón) 2. Operar con eso en el servidor (insertar, leer, borrar...) 3. Recibir una respuesta del servidor (se insertó con éxito, se borró, hubo error...) 4. Mostrar ...

Comment: ... esa respuesta en el cliente. Y, lo más importante: todo eso **sin tener que recargar o refrescar la página**. Ahora bien, si es un ejercicio, puede que no te permitan usar herramientas como Ajax o Fetch y debas resolverlo **a la antigua**. Tiene sentido para aprender cómo funciona php, pero para aplicaciones futuras que quede claro que las cosas han cambiando mucho con respecto a enviar y recibir datos entre cliente / servidor, actualizar la interfaz gráfica con información dinámica, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Para recorrer la informacion tiene que hacerlo desde el while del fetch

```
$Return = "";
while ($fila = $resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $CodPed = $fila['CodPed'];
    $Fecha = $fila['Fecha'];
    $Enviado = $fila['Enviado'];
    $Return = $Return . "<tr><td>$CodPed</td><td>$Fecha</td><td>$Enviado</td></tr>"
}
return $Return;
```

Ya luego la variable $resultado la imprimi en la tabla

```
<tbody>
<?php
    echo $resultado;
?>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 2):

Bueno además de las respuestas ya dadas, podría acotar que no necesariamente tienes que utilizar un `while` ya que en *PDO* tienes la opción de utilizar [fetchAll](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetchall.php):

> ### PDOStatement::fetchAll
>
> (PHP 5 >= 5.1.0, PHP 7, PHP 8, PECL pdo >= 0.1.0)
>
> **PDOStatement::fetchAll** — Devuelve un array que contiene todas las filas del conjunto de resultados.
>
> **Ejemplo de uso:**
>
> ```
> <?php
> $gsent = $gbd->prepare("SELECT name, colour FROM fruit");
> $gsent->execute();
> $resultado = $gsent->fetchAll();
> print_r($resultado);
> ```

En tu caso el código seria de la siguiente forma:

```
function comprobarHistorial($usuario,$fecha){
    $base=conexionBD();
    $consulta="SELECT CodPed, Fecha, Enviado FROM pedidos INNER JOIN 
           hospitales 
           ON pedidos.Hospital=hospitales.CodHosp 
           WHERE pedidos.Fecha=:fecha AND pedidos.Hospital=:usuario";
    $resultado=$base->prepare($consulta);
    $resultado->bindParam(":fecha",$fecha);
    $resultado->bindParam(":usuario",$usuario);
    $resultado->execute();

    // Aquí retornamos todas las filas
    return $resultado->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Como ves de esta forma te ahorras el trabajo de hacer el `while` y retornas las filas con una sola línea de código ;).

Comment: Subrayar que lo que parece una ventaja (el uso de `fetchAll`), puede convertirse en un problema en algunos escenarios. Cuando se esperan muchos datos el uso de `fetchAll()` puede desbordar la memoria, haciendo que el código falle. Ver [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/184343/29967) para más detalles.

Comment: mmm podría darse el caso de carga de miles de millones de datos como dice la respuesta que agregas pero la verdad en todos mis años no me he llegado a topar con ese escenario con semejante cantidad de información cargadas de un tirón, no estoy seguro si podría llegar a darse ya que incluso el tiempo de carga seria un padecimiento, de todas formas me parece buena la información que mencionas. ;)

Comment: No tendrían que ser miles de millones, podrían ser varios miles de filas, por ejemplo, una consulta del tipo `SELECT * FROM unaTablaCon500MilRegistros` sin ningún tipo de filtro ejecutada de forma concurrente y/o en un servidor con poca capacidad, o desde un cliente con una conexión lenta. La cuestión es que esto depende de varios escenarios. Lo que he comentado sobre `fetchAll` viene advertido en el Manual de PHP. No creo que se deba programar pensando: *bueno, no soy la NASA, no voy a manejar nunca millones de datos*. Hay que tratar siempre de optimizar el código, aunque no seas la NASA.